# Как отследить прокрутку NestedScrollView вверх или вниз?

Tags: java, android, nested-scrollview

У меня имеется `NestedScrollView`, как корневой элемент и есть кнопка которая перекрывает часть контента. Как отследить, что `NestedScrollView` прокручивается вниз, что бы в этот момент скрыть кнопку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно в метод **setOnScrollChangeListener** Вашего **NestedScrollView** передать свою реализацию интерфейса **OnScrollChangeListener**. В этом интерфейсе есть всего один метод

```
void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY,
                int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY);
```

Используя параметры **scrollY** и **oldScrollY** можно определить куда скролит пользователь.

Comment: спасибо большое, это то, что нужно